# Template argument deduce from scope resolution

Tags: c++, template-argument-deduction

i have my base and derived class as below

```
class Disposable : public PolymorphicE
{
protected:
    virtual void Created() {}
    virtual void Disposing() {}
public:
    template <typename DisposableClass, typename ... Args>
    static DisposableClass* Create(Args&& ... constructorArgs)
    {
        DisposableClass* result = new DisposableClass(std::forward<Args>(constructorArgs)...);
        result->Created();
        return result;
    }

    void Dispose()
    {
        Disposing();
        delete this;
    }
};

class MyClass : public Disposable
{
public:
    MyClass(int param1, double param2) {}
};
```

and this is how i create my objects

```
MyClass::Create<MyClass>(45, 23.74);

//i want it this way instead
MyClass::Create(45, 23.74);
```

i read (from an unrelated topic) that "deducing from left side of "::" is not possible.
Is there any other way i can implement this (if i can not deduce it from left side of "::") so i can create objects like this "MyClass::Create(45, 23.74);"

(I realise that compiler wouldn't know my real-intention with a static base class method, so it can understand that it is a constructor and help me deducing, but i was hoping maybe there are some helping keywords or standard library syntax that overcome this kind of issues)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The typical approach for this is the *curiously recurring template pattern* (CRTP):

```
class Disposable : public PolymorphicE
{
protected:
    virtual void Created() {}
    virtual void Disposing() {}
public:
    void Dispose()
    {
        Disposing();
        delete this;
    }
};

template<typename Derived>
struct DisposableWithCreate : public Disposable
{
    template <typename ... Args>
    static Derived* Create(Args&& ... constructorArgs)
    {
        Derived* result = new Derived(std::forward<Args>(constructorArgs)...);
        result->Created();
        return result;
    }
};

class MyClass : public DisposableWithCreate<MyClass>
{
public:
    MyClass(int param1, double param2) {}
};
```

And now it will work without having to define `Create` in every class derived from `Disposable` through `DisposableWithCreate`.

If you need to derive further from `MyClass`, the following might help:

```
class Disposable
{
protected:
    virtual void Created() {}
    virtual void Disposing() {}
public:
    void Dispose()
    {
        Disposing();
        delete this;
    }

    template<typename Derived>
    struct CRTP
    {
        template <typename ... Args>
        static Derived* Create(Args&& ... constructorArgs)
        {
            Derived* result = new Derived(std::forward<Args>(constructorArgs)...);
            result->Created();
            return result;
        }
    };
};

class MyClass : public Disposable, public Disposable::CRTP<MyClass>
{
public:
    MyClass(int param1, double param2) {}
};

class MyClass2 : public MyClass, public Disposable::CRTP<MyClass2>
{
public:
    MyClass2(int param1, double param2);
    using Disposable::CRTP<MyClass2>::Create;
};
```

Comment: i tried your answer and worked realy well. This is a clever method solve my problem, however this would work only for single derived classes, if i derive another class from an existing derived class, i have to implement another CRTP helping class for that derived one.

Comment: @IbrahimOzdemir See edit for a suggestion.